# Simplifying $\sum_{t=1}^{n}t^2v^t$ using actuarial notation.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

In financial mathematics involving immunization, I encounter situations where I am trying to calculate

$$(A) \quad v+4v^2+9v^3+ \cdots +n^2v^n=\sum_{t=1}^{n}t^2v^t $$

where $v$ is the present value factor.

I understand that

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n}v^t=a_{\overline{n}\rceil}$$

is the annuity immediate present value factor and

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n}tv^t=(Ia)_{\overline{n}\rceil}=\frac{\ddot{a}_{\overline{n}\rceil}-nv^n}{i}$$

is the increasing annuity immediate present value factor.

Once understood, I find these simplifications very convenient and I tried to come up with a formula for eqn. (A)

Using the fact that

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n}tx^t=\frac{x-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

taking the derivative on both sides and multiplying $x$ gives me something similar to (A)
which I think is

$$(B) \ \quad \sum_{t=1}^{n}t^2x^t=\frac{2x^2(1-x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n})}{(1-x)^3}-n(n+1)x^{n+2}-\frac{nx^{n+3}}{1-x}$$

I was simply wondering if there are any known formulae for eqn. (A) using actuarial notation.  Trying to deduce something from (B) is quite a tackle for me and I am not confident that I can simplify this.

Comment: First of all it is $$\sum_{t=1}^{n}tx^t=\frac{\color{red} x -x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  I will change that.

Comment: From my knowledge, there isn't any general actuarial notation for it - largely because it doesn't have a particularly relevant purpose of itself. I guess it depends on what they plan on teaching you, but what I was taught is that in practice you'll be using numerical methods to find the convexity - since analytical solutions are unnecessarily complex to find.

Edit: Or were you just trying to get at least part of it in actuarial notation?

Comment: @mardat In my case I was just curious.  Especially because finding the Macaulay Duration with actuarial notation becomes a nice looking expression and for immunization problems the second derivative is literally just one more derivative away from the first.  So, I was wondering if there were any known formula that has been used before computers became a major part of being an actuary.

Comment: @hyg17 fair enough. What you've got above is about as simple as it gets, but a more useful way to find convexity is $\frac{1}{V(i)}\times\frac{V(i+h)-2V(i)+V(i-h)}{h^2}$ where $V(i)$ is the present value for interest rate $i$. So long as you choose a reasonably small $h$, this will give you a value that might as well be the exact value from the formula, but with a lot less computation.